# Android studio - button styles not applying

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

For some reason my custom button styling isn't applying properly.

It applies in the design view for the layout, but as soon as I run it in the emulator or on my phone, the buttons are the same colour as the background and don't change when they're pressed.

Here is `button_style.xml` (in the drawables folder):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#707070">
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#00C7FC" />
        <stroke
            android:width="4dp"
            android:color="#9FEDFF" />
        <corners
            android:radius="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:color="#707070">
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="#eeeeee" />
        <corners
            android:radius="0dp" />
        <elevation
            android:elevation="2dp" />

    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Here is `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.st1.u3141294.sparkscientificcalculator">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="SparK"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".sparkMain">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And finally here is the block of code from one of my buttons linked to `button_style.xml`:

```
<Button
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClickNormal" />
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong, any suggestions?

Comment: Please remove this android:textColor property from button in XML.

Comment: You can't add `android:color="#707070"` in `<item>` tag.